# Today angular opens debugger after refresh on localhost , why?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Today, after refreshing my angular app, debugger (PAUSED ON DEBUGGER) is always opening. Why ?

Debugger shows these lines of code (Not mine - core.js) :

```
/**
 * Instantiate all the directives that were previously resolved on the current node.
 */
function instantiateAllDirectives(tView, lView, tNode, native) {
    const start = tNode.directiveStart;
    const end = tNode.directiveEnd;
    if (!tView.firstCreatePass) {    // THIS IS WHERE DEBUGGER OPENS
        getOrCreateNodeInjectorForNode(tNode, lView);
    }
    attachPatchData(native, lView);
    const initialInputs = tNode.initialInputs;
    for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
        const def = tView.data[i];
        const isComponent = isComponentDef(def);
        if (isComponent) {
            ngDevMode && assertNodeOfPossibleTypes(tNode, [3 /* Element */]);
            addComponentLogic(lView, tNode, def);
        }
        const directive = getNodeInjectable(lView, tView, i, tNode);
        attachPatchData(directive, lView);
        if (initialInputs !== null) {
            setInputsFromAttrs(lView, i - start, directive, def, tNode, initialInputs);
        }
        if (isComponent) {
            const componentView = getComponentLViewByIndex(tNode.index, lView);
            componentView[CONTEXT] = directive;
        }
    }
}
```

**How to fix it ? Yesterday it worked perfect.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you doesn’t put it on yours code it could be added by dev tools check next places where it could be added[image]

Comment: I see that it is in core.js

Comment: Does deactivate breakpoints fix the problem or it will only fix it for me ?

Comment: And i checked on other browsers, only appears on chrome.

Comment: Yes, when you deactivate it will fix

Comment: So a normal user has it deactivated always ?

Comment: No, this breakpoint was added by you, could be occasionally. Check it on private window in chrome